# Is a still object in 4D spacetime lightlike?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors, causality

Every particle in the universe is moving in spacetime: a massive "still" one (in the 3D sense) is moving in a purely timelike direction, a massive "moving" one in a direction with both timelike and spacelike components (but obviously timelike in total), a photon in a lightlike direction. We even theorized the tachyons that would move in a spacelike direction. But what about something that just doesn't change its coordinates, never, remaining in the same point of a manifold?

- Can it have a consistent explanation in Relativity?
- Would it be interesting?
- Would it be described as lightlike since its norm would be, well, zero?

Note: I'm *not* asking whether this case is physical: I know that it isn't. Tachyons aren't physical either, but they are mathematical objects that can be studied in Relativity.

Comment: A particle that is created in a collision, and quickly decay in another one, is like a point in spacetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it have a consistent explanation in Relativity?

If I understand it right, what you talking about is a single point $p$ in spacetime, may call it an event. So yeah, it is well defined as $p\in M$. However, it is unintresting as it does not posess any dynamics per se. As you said, it remains at the same point of the manifold.

> Would it be described as lightlike since its norm would be, well, zero?

The "norm" is not defined on the spacetime but on its tangent spaces. Thus, you cannot call a single point/event light-, space- or time-like.

One thing I might add is that you can interpret the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of a differential equation, take for example the wave equation $$(\partial_t^2 - \Delta)\psi = 0, $$ as the solution of the equation for a point like source (possibly in spacetime), i.e. a solution of $$(\partial_t^2 - \Delta)G(x,t) = \delta(x,t).$$ This might fits a little what you are searching for. However, it is just an interpretation of a mathematical tool and should not be taken too serious.

To come to a conclusion, a object sitting on a single point in spacetime is probably best described by that point $p$ but unintressting as it does not have any dynamics. Tachyons in turn have dynamical properties that can be studied. I hope this somehow helps you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> But what about something that just doesn't change its coordinates, never, remaining in the same point of a manifold?

The world lines of particles with non-zero restmass are timelike curves within the lightcone. If at rest or not doesn't matter. A particle at rest moves through spacetime, which is all time in this case.

"At rest" in spacetime requires to stop  time. You can't stop time for a particle though. If you could there would be no worldline und thus questioning of timelike vs spacelike etc. would be meaningless. You can connect two points on a spacelike hypersurface to obtain a spacelike wordline, but that's another story.

Comment: This case is the one I already said in the post. I don't mean "at rest" in the spatial way, but in the spacetime way. When I say "its coordinates" I mean all of them, $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.